# How to edit objects together

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I understand that the green lines are groups,is there a way to edit them all together,or to ungroup them and then regroup them all into a single object?

This is what happens when I enter edit mode:
[image]
My goal is to be able to edit all of the green lines together so that I can fill the gaps in between them like this:
[image]

I'm sorry if I didn't explain the issue correctly,I'm a beginner and this is the first time that I ask something.

Comment: Thank you all for your time,I managed to solve the issue! By making the lines into a mesh I can now edit it as I intended too.

Answer (score 2):

Select the objects in object mode, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. They are now merged into a single object.

Since these are curve type object, connecting them with faces is not that easy. I would suggest that you convert your new object to a mesh. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Text*

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do depends on exactly what the lines are.  If all the lines are strings of connected vertices, like the one selected in your screen shot, then switch to Object mode, select them all, then press Ctrl-J to combine them into a single object.  Now when you switch to Edit mode you can select vertices on  adjacent lines and press F to create a face between them.

If all the elements are not strings of connected vertices, explain how you generated them and what they are, so I or someone else can help you solve your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: Answer should not ask for clarification. Use the comment functionality once you have enough reputation. Until then, leave out questions and meta information.